# ¿Como puedo meter una variable de la misma clase que la clase que estoy definiendo?

Tags: c++, punteros, class

Estoy realizando un problema de A* y necesito guardar el padre para luego imprimir el recorrido. El todo funciona correctamente hasta que en el método de imprimir le pido el nodo padre y me da este error:

> "error.EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Os dejo los todos los pedazos donde aparece esta variable.

```
class node{

private:

    node *padre;
    vector<vector <string>>situacion;
    int profundidad;
    int g = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int f = 0;
    string paso;

public:

    node getPadre(){

     return *padre;
   }

   void setPadre(node newPadre){

    padre = &newPadre;
   }
};

// ...

newNode.setPadre(nodo); //Donde "nodo es una variable de la clase node"

// ...

node itNode = itNode.getPadre(); // donde it node
```

El problema es que guardo los nodos en una `vector<nodes>` y la reorganizo con *sort* en cada iteración, con lo que las memorias cambian, y por eso al intentar acceder al nodo padre, no esta ahí.

¿Sabéis si hay alguna manera de hacer un sort con un `vector<*node>`?

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos los que respondáis o lo intentéis.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, te agradecería que la reformularas. Lo que entiendo es que te quejas de no poder tener un no-puntero a tu propia clase ¿es así?

Comment: Me gustaría tener un no-puntero si. Pero de no ser posible arreglar este problema aunque sea con un puntero.

Comment: He encontrado el error, he editado la pregunta, ¿sabrías decirme algo?

Comment: No puedes tener un no-puntero (instancia) a la clase que estás construyendo porque necesitas que sea la clase completa. Necesitas que sea la clase completa porque necesitas saber el tamaño de la clase, y si tienes una instancia de tu clase dentro de tu clase, el tamaño es recursivamente infinito.

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta te la ha dado @Trauma , tu nueva pregunta de ordenar vectores es eso: una nueva pregunta. Te animo a aceptar su respuesta (ganarás dos puntitos) y a abrir una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void setPadre(node newPadre){
  padre = &newPadre;
}
```

Fíjate que le estás pasando **una copia**, no el objeto original. Por lo tanto, lo que estás almacenando es una posición de memória que **deja de ser correcta en cuanto sales de tu función**.

La solución es sencilla:

```
void setPadre( node &newPadre){
  padre = &newPadre;
}
```

Es decir: **pasarlo por referencia**, no por valor.

Comment: He encontrado el error, he editado la pregunta ¿sabrías resolverlo ahora?

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez Iba a editar, pero he visto el comentario de PaperBirdMaster, y estoy de acuerdo: debes de formular una nueva pregunta. Te sugiero que mires la 3 forma: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort. Y busca algo sobre *lambdas* en C++11

Comment: Muchas gracias!!